# JPA null parameters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to fetch all rows that match a parameter or fetch all of them if it's null

I've (not) found a solution reading the Spring Data [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.nullability.annotations) - **Example 21. Using different** nullability constraints

Tried the example using the annotation `@Nullable`, but still doesn't work, here's the code

```
// just a part of entity LotMaster 
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "lot_master_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sq_lot_master_gen", sequenceName = "sq_lot_master", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "lot_id")
private Long id;

//repository extends JpaRepository<LotMaster, Long>
@Nullable
Page<LotMaster> findAllById(@Nullable Long id, Pageable p);
```

Query:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         lot0_.lot_id              AS lot1_2_,
         lot0_.qty                 AS qty_2_,
         lot0_.version             AS version8_2_,
         lot0_.username            AS username15_2_
      FROM
         lot_master lot0_
      WHERE
         lot0_.lot_id IS NULL
   )
WHERE
   ROWNUM <= ?
```

As u see, it's using the null value as a condition instead of ignoring it

[Pic Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66n3e.png)

How is possible? Any idea without CriteriaApi or using **@Query**
My idea is to add more few more parameters and use derived query

Possibly related [DATAJPA-209](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-209)

> I realize that using id as example it confuses, sorry for that.
>   However If I use another field like qty I should have the possibility
>   to search even with null. In a form multiple fields that can be left
>   empy. Would be nice an implementation like `@RequestParam` with required
>   or defaultValue parameters or simply `@Nullable` working

Comment: That `DATAJPA-209` ticket is about the different semantics of `= NULL` and `IS NULL` in databases. I'd be **really** surprised if you could do that without a `@Query`, and even if you could, it would only be confusing.

Comment: Don't. Either use predicates if you want to do this or if there is no `id` use the regular `findAll`. But please don't try to write a single query method to rule them all.

Comment: @M.Deinum I realize that using `id` as example it confuses, sorry for that. However If I use another field like `qty` I should have the possibility to search even with null. In a form multiple fields that can be left empy. Would be nice an implementation like `@RequestParam` with `required` or `defaultValue` parameters or simply `@Nullable` working

Comment: @Kayaman it's also refers to the fact that _If a null value is passed in to a query method, the JPQL generated includes an "= NULL" condition, which is always false._

Comment: @MikeyMargotrin that's *exactly* what I was referring to.

Comment: As stated use predicates (which are basically using the criteria API) instead of trying to write a catch all query.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to `findAllByIdOrId(@Nullable Long id, Long id2)` and pass `null` as one of params. Kind of a dull and easier to do with `@Query`.

Another approach is to do `findAllByIdOrIdIsNull(Long id)` but that would yeld